# Alt+Tab on Fluxbox

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, fluxbox

I've been using Fluxbox on my netbook, and have been very pleased. That is, with everything but one feature. I would really like it if I could use Fluxbox with the added functionality that when I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it will show me the windows I am switching between. (As it does in Windows/Mac/GNOME/KDE/Xfce/...). Is there some app I can install that would do that? Or is the only resort to use a different GUI?

Comment: Cross posted on [AU](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86864/alttab-on-fluxbox).

Comment: [Do not cross-post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting).

Comment: Have you ever found out how to do that? I am interested in achieving this functionality as well.

Comment: @enzotib: the AU post has been closed.   I would also live to know how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Traditional Alt-Tab (not only keyboard shortcut, but GUI list) may be achieved by [alttab](https://github.com/sagb/alttab).
It works nicely in fluxbox.

Install `alttab`.

Disable/comment built-in non-GUI Alt-Tab in `/etc/X11/fluxbox/keys` or `~/.fluxbox/keys`:

```
#Mod1 Tab :NextWindow {groups} (workspace=[current])
#Mod1 Shift Tab :PrevWindow {groups} (workspace=[current])
```

Edit `~/.fluxbox/startup`:

```
...other apps...
alttab &
exec fluxbox
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use http://bbkeys.sourceforge.net/ to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is also a git repo](https://github.com/naimdjon/bbkeys) with installation instructions for `bbkeys`. Make sure to remove the key bindings from your `~/.fluxbox/keys` file.